# Unbreakable Loop in Unity, not sure how to fix. Causing Unity to crash

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a "combo" system in unity but I've created an Unbreakable loop which I'm struggling to understand. I've tried using a while loop and had this issue so wanted to give a for loop a go as well, but I'm having the same result.

The way the combo system should work is that when the player enters a condition with an enemy, they can enter a chain of buttons on the controller to trigger a combo. If the player enters the correct combo, effects are applied. So far I'm only worried about getting the combo system work.

I've created a pre-defined array of chars for the combo, and then I compare an input from the player to this array.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ComboSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public char currentButton;
    public char[] combo_arr = { 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'X' };

    PlayerLockOnSystem plos;

    private void Start()
    {
        plos = GetComponent<PlayerLockOnSystem>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (plos.lockedOn)
        {
            Combo();
        }
    }

    void DetectComboButtons()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Joystick A"))
        {
            currentButton = 'A';
        }

        if (Input.GetButton("Joystick X"))
        {
            currentButton = 'X';
        }

        if (Input.GetButton("Joystick B"))
        {
            currentButton = 'B';
        }


    }

    void Combo()
    {



        for (int i = 0; i < combo_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            DetectComboButtons();

            if (currentButton == combo_arr[i])
            {

                Debug.Log("Correct: " + currentButton);
            }
            else
            {
                i = 0;
                Debug.Log("Incorrect");
            }
        }






    }




}
```

When the Combo() method is triggered, Unity crashes and I have to force close the editor.

Comment: You need to add a while loop and a delay to `DetectComboButtons`. The code doesn't wait for for an input, it simply returns the pressed key, or nothing if no keys are being pressed. You need to wait for an input

Comment: You're setting i =0 in the loop which is causing the infinite loop. You have to keep track of the player's current button press and the current index into the combo they are at.. if the next button is incorrect reset the current combo index.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'm still a bit unsure as to what you mean, I'm sorry if this is a really basic thing that I'm just not fully aware of

Comment: See if [this guide](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/KeyCombo) is of any help.

Comment: Okay I'll have a look! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the input between frames, in different calls of update. Try this:

```
private const char CHAR_THAT_MEANS_THAT_THE_PLAYER_DIDNT_BREAK_THE_CHAIN = '0';//doesnt matter

private int _currentPlaceInTheComboChain = 0;

private void Update()
{
    if (plos.lockedOn)
    {
        Combo();
    }
}

char DetectComboButtons()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Joystick A"))
    {
        return 'A';
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Joystick X"))
    {
        return 'X';
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Joystick B"))
    {
        return 'B';
    }
 return CHAR_THAT_MEANS_THAT_THE_PLAYER_DIDNT_BREAK_THE_CHAIN;


}

void Combo()
{
    char currentButton = DetectComboButtons();
    if (currentButton == CHAR_THAT_MEANS_THAT_THE_PLAYER_DIDNT_BREAK_THE_CHAIN) 
    {
       return; //the player didn't continue the combo but didn't break it (yet)
    } 

    if (currentButton == combo_arr[_currentPlaceInTheComboChain])
    {
       _currentPlaceInTheComboChain++;//wait for the next button, will only be checked the next time update is called
       Debug.Log("Correct: " + currentButton);
       if (_currentPlaceInTheComboChain == combo_arr.Length) { //this was the last button in the combo
           _currentPlaceInTheComboChain = 0; //for a new combo
           Debug.Log("Combo completed");
       }
    } else {
      _currentPlaceInTheComboChain = 0; //player broke the chain
      Debug.Log("Incorrect " + currentButton);
    }

}
```

Comment: Good news, it's no longer running an infinite loop,the code kinda work. When I press the correct button, the console outputs both correct and incorrect and doesn't seem to advance any further.

Comment: You mean it only recognized the first but didn't proceed and didnt reach "combo complete" or it does continue one button at a time as you want it to?

Comment: It doesn't appear to advance as the "Combo complete" doesn't ever appear in my log. This is what I get after pressing the correct combo https://prntscr.com/ni9v4b

Comment: Oh, you need to use GetButtonDown and not getButton otherwise a press too long will be considered as 2 or more presses

Comment: The code could probably be simplified a bit (possibly utilizing a coroutine), but the answer isn't wrong.  Tom, you may want to edit the answer to use `GetButtonDown` as well.